# React: Cannot update during an existing state transitio

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with React.
When I press the "+" button, this console message appears and nothing happens:

```
Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`
```

I found several questions with similar titles, but common thing among them is that there were calls of functions with `setState` inside render method.

My render method has no calls, but error appears.

Why?

Thank you for reading.

Code:

```
import React from 'react';

const TodoForm = ({addTodo}) => {
    let input;

    return (
        <div>
            <input
                ref={node => {
                    input = node;
                }}

            />
            <button onClick={() => {
                addTodo(input.value);
                input.value = '';
            }}>
                +
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};


const Todo = ({todo, remove}) => {
    // Each Todo
    return (<li onClick={remove(todo.id)}>{todo.text}</li>)
};

const TodoList = ({todos, remove}) => {
    // Map through the todos
    const todoNode = todos.map((todo) => {
        return (<Todo todo={todo} key={todo.id} remove={remove}/>)
    });
    return (<ul>{todoNode}</ul>);
};

const Title = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <h1>to-do</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

window.id = 0;
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        // Pass props to parent class
        super(props);
        // Set initial state
        this.state = {
            data: []
        }
    }

    // Add todo handler
    addTodo(val) {
        // Assemble data
        const todo = {text: val, id: window.id++}
        // Update data
        this.state.data.push(todo);
        // Update state
        console.log('setting state...');
        this.setState({data: this.state.data});
    }

    // Handle remove
    handleRemove(id) {
        // Filter all todos except the one to be removed
        const remainder = this.state.data.filter((todo) => {
            if (todo.id !== id) return todo;
        });
        // Update state with filter
        this.setState({data: remainder});
    }

    render() {
        // Render JSX
        return (
            <div>
                <Title />
                <TodoForm addTodo={
                    (val)=>{

                        this.addTodo(val)
                    }
                }/>
                <TodoList
                    todos={this.state.data}
                    remove={this.handleRemove.bind(this)}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default TodoApp;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your render method for `Todo` you invoke `remove`, which is where your erroneous state update happens.

To fix this, return a function from the `handleRemove` method of `TodoApp` that updates the state. Simplified version:

```
handleRemove(id) {
  return () => {
    ...
    this.setState({ data: remainder });
  }
}
```

Also worth noting here that because you're using the current state, it's best to use the `setState` callback (which gets `prevState` as an argument), and not rely on `this.state`.

[setState docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Comment: Do you mean handleRemove method?

Comment: Thanks a lot, you really helped!

Answer (score 0):

Andy_D very helped and my answer has two solutions:

First in render function change

```
<TodoList
    todos={this.state.data}
    remove={this.handleRemove.bind(this)}
/>
```

to

```
<TodoList
    todos={this.state.data}
    remove={() => this.handleRemove.bind(this)}
/>
```

or change code

```
const Todo = ({todo, remove}) => {
    // Each Todo
    return (<li onClick={remove(todo.id)}>{todo.text}</li>)
};
```

to that:

```
const Todo = ({todo, remove}) => {
    // Each Todo
    return (<li onClick={() => remove(todo.id)}>{todo.text}</li>)
};
```